# Windows GUI application in Docker containers

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I have created a simple Hello World GUI application. This is the docker file,

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.2007
ADD ./TestDocker/* /
CMD c:\TestDocker.exe
```

I build it using:

```
docker build -t test-docker-i .
```

I run it using:

```
docker run -it test-docker-i
```

I see TestDocker.exe in the task manager, but no GUI shown. Can anyone point me if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: This  is a Windows (not Linux) Docker container, I take it?

Comment: Yes. Windows container.

Comment: Do you have documentation that says this is possible?  The only information I've seen on the subject says (a) it can't be done, or (b) it _can_ be done, but the results will be what you see: the app is running, but you can't see it.  The trouble seems to be (among other things) that you'd need to RDP into the container to see some kind of visual, and RDP isn't supported in Windows Docker containers.